# How concept of spin comes theoretically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, quantum-spin

Spin comes from Dirac's theory. Does it only comes from the fact that relativistic Dirac equation is Lorentz invariant?

Comment: https://av.tib.eu/media/11186